# accessing children's properties after creating several Views

Tags: android, view, textview

Let's assume I have a `ScrollView` and an `Actionbar` button which adds Views to the `ScrollView`. This `View` holds a simple `EditText`. A user can add as many `Views` as he wants to and assigns each `View` a unique number. Am I able to access each `View` and read its number?

```
// View to add
addView() {
   newView = (ViewGroup) ...inflate(R...);
   text = (EditText) findViewById();
   scrollView.addView(newView); }
```

After the user added several `Views` and gave each `TextView` a number, I want to read those numbers and store them in an `ArrayList<String>`.
I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop through them

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
ViewGroup vg = scrollView.getChildAt(0); // get its direct child
for(int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++){
  //we loop through the views in the scrollview's direct 
  //child and get the views and do what we want to do
  strings.add(((EditText)vg.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString());
}
```